# Redirect paths to subdirectories in htaccess in any dir

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In Apache2 I want to redirect some paths to specified directories and all others to other dir using htaccess.

### Working configuration

In my root Apache2 dir (`/var/www/html`) I've a structure:

```
/var/www/html
├── a
│   ├── aa.html
│   ├── .htaccess
│   └── index.html
├── b
│   ├── bb.html
│   └── index.html
├── .htaccess
└── index.html
```

My root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect some paths to the /a
RewriteRule ^x(.*)$ /a/$1 [L]

# Redirect everything else to /b/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/b/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /b/$1 [L]
# or
#RewriteRule !^b/ /b%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

And it works good:

- root index.html is never displayed,
- http://localhost/x displays a/index.html
- http://localhost/x/aa.html displays a/aa.html
- http://localhost/x/a/b/c/ is handled by a/.htaccess
- http://localhost/ displays b/index.html
- http://localhost/bb.html displays b/bb.html

### The problem

Now I want to make exactly the same redirections, but starting from any subdirectory as root for my paths, for example userdir on linux.

Lets say I've structure:

```
/home/radzikowski/public_html/test
├── aa
│   ├── aa.html
│   ├── .htaccess
│   └── index.html
├── bb
│   └── index.html
├── .htaccess
└── index.html
```

Now:

- http://localhost/~radzikowski/test/x should display aa/index.html
- http://localhost/~radzikowski/test/x/aa.html displays aa/aa.html
- http://localhost/~radzikowski/test/x/a/b/c/ should be handled by aa/.htaccess
- http://localhost/~radzikowski/test/ should display bb/index.html
- http://localhost/~radzikowski/test/bb.html should display bb/bb.html

Using the same .htaccess of course tries to use files from `/var/www/html`, for example http://localhost/~radzikowski/test/ redirects (internally) to http://localhost/bb/ and tries to load `/var/www/html/bb/index.html`.

I've tried with `BASE` variable, but without success. For example this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^%{ENV:BASE}/bb/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/bb/$1 [L]
```

results in HTTP 500 error caused by to many redirections.

### Question

How my `/home/radzikowski/public_html/test/.htaccess` file should look like to redirect given paths to subdirectories?

Using hardcoded `RewriteBase` is not an option, this configuration should be location independent.

Apache mod rewrite config is not a problem, it is enabled for userdir (and has `AllowOverride All`).

Answer (score 0):

Try these 2 rules in your `/test/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect some paths to the /a
RewriteRule ^x(/.*)?$ a$1 [L,NC]

# Redirect everything else to /b/    
RewriteRule !^b/ b%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: This does not work. In fact it's similar to my htaccess in main dir and it fails in every subdir. I'm getting `404 Not found: /home/radzikowski/public_html/test/b/~radzikowski/test/`
Whats interesting without %{REQUEST_URI} I'm getting `404 Not found: /home/radzikowski/public_html/test/b`although that dir exists and can be opened directly from webbrowser.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located and what is full URL you're entering in browser?

Comment: URL: `http://localhost/~radzikowski/test/`
Path: `/home/mradzikowski/public_html/test/` and here I've `.htaccess` and dirs `a` and `b`.
I've deleted all files from `/var/www/html` just to be sure. In `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf` I've `AllowOverride All` and `Options All`.
Browser cache is disabled.